# How to add offset of 3 seconds to linux system clock?

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a python script that is triggered by CRON every 5 mins. This python script then does some checks and then calls another python script many times with different configurations. Those other python scripts are trading bots and they need to be called separately for each trading pair so I end up calling this second script about 50 times (each time with a different config).

The problem I have is that between my first python script being started by CRON and then the subsequent python scripts being called, about 5 to 8 seconds pass (I am using subprocess.Popen to open the secondary scripts) and this 8 seconds makes a huge difference in trading.

So what I would like to know, is if there is a way to offset my system clock by say, 5 seconds so that the secondary scripts are called as close as possible to the actual start of the minute?

Comment: Are you sure you have to use a separate process for the other jobs? If you did it in the same process, it would be significantly faster. You could also not use a cron job at all, but have a python process running constantly and doing things exactly on the start of a minute.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. The best solution probably does *not* involve offsetting your system clock, but rather finding a faster way to check and open the subprocesses, or possibly just execute everything in one process. If it takes 5 to 8 seconds just to start the subprocesses, there's probably a faster way. If the "checks" performed by the primary script take 5 to 8 seconds, perhaps that time can also be reduced. If the "checks" don't need to be synchronized with the system clock at all, then they can be performed eagerly.

Comment: I use a separate process so that I can execute the secondary script 50 times in parallel. Otherwise, it would be executed in sequence and so that last of the 50 execution would be several seconds after the 1st of the 50 executions

Comment: "If the "checks" performed by the primary script take 5 to 8 seconds, perhaps that time can also be reduced" -> The checks take 5 to 8 seconds but I also just noticed that the secondary script also takes a few secs (3 to 4) to reach the point where it creates the trading order so even those 3 to 4 secs would be great to eliminate.

Comment: @amichaelix I would look into threads, or possibly asyncio. Since you're likely using some sort of API, a lot of the time is probably spent in a non-GIL state waiting for network IO.

Comment: Since you're in the market for hacks, you can add `sleep 297` before the `*/5` cron job. This will cause the script to run at 12:04:57, 12:09:57, etc :P